# Webpack - SET NODE_ENV=development & webpack ... SyntaxError

Tags: webpack, модули, node-modules

Следую инструкциям из урока - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XZqeuWkQ4o&index=6&list=PLDyvV36pndZHfBThhg4Z0822EEG9VGenn

И всё было хорошо, до момента ввода команды в консоли:

> SET NODE_ENV=development & webpack

которая выводит **SyntaxError**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я уже перепробовал все возможные комбинации из комментариев - ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать не присваивание, а JSON синтаксис.
В строке 22 должно быть как-то так:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'USER'])
]
```

Comment: спасибо! вместо "=" нужно было ":" просто...

Comment: слушай, тут ещё одна мелочь.. в welcome.js прописано if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development"), и после того как я в консоли пишу SET NODE_ENV=development & webpack - в build.js должно быть if (true), а оно if (false)

Comment: @1px_solid_black, пришлось смотреть Кантора, что-бы понять суть вопроса. Попробуй просто выведи значение **process.env.NODE_ENV**.

Comment: =) я уже понял, спасибо.. вместо SET NODE_ENV=development & webpack, нужно отправлять SET "NODE_ENV=development" & webpack, то есть в кавычках